# Setting up local domain in Linux

Tags: php

I have a PHP project named **sample** in my localhost and can be runned using the url *localhost/workspace/sample*. How can I run the same by setting up a local domain say example.com. I am using LAMP.

Comment: "localhost" is your local domain.

Comment: yes..now I want to run the project as example.com instead of localhost/workspace/sample.

Comment: all you need to know is described here: http://linux.die.net/man/3/gethostbyaddr and here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_hosting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem without changing domain name of localhost.

The steps done are:
1) Add hostname in **/etc/hosts** file
Eg: `127.0.0.1  example.com`

2) Edit **/etc/apache2/httpd.conf** file and add the following lines.
`NameVirtualHost *:80`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www
```

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName example.com
DocumentRoot "/home/user/workspace/sample"
<Directory /home/user/workspace/sample>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

3) Create a file with your domain name say, example.com in **/etc/apache2/sites-available** folder with the following lines.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName example.com
DocumentRoot /home/user/workspace/sample
<Directory /home/user/workspace/sample>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

4) Restart apache server

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo nano /etc/hosts
```

add the line:

```
127.0.0.1       example.com
```

press `ctrl+x`, `y` to save, then `enter`

this will make all requests to `example.com` point to `127.0.0.1` (which is `localhost`), so if you want to make this work across a network (or from a virtual machine) just repeat the steps above, though use the host machines ip address in place of `127.0.0.1`

Comment: Would have been awesome if you had added name based virtual host config with document root to `/workspace/sample`.

Comment: I don't want to change the localhost to example.com. What I need is to change a project in localhost to example.com.

Comment: ah right, you still need this step (to override your dns), though you'll also need to setup a virtual host in addition, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/18200847/977939

Comment: I need localhost as localhost itself. Only one project inside the workspace needs to have domain as example.com.

Answer (score 2):

You want to look into changing your /etc/hosts file to point to your localhost.

Essentially you will capture the request before it has a chance to go to DNS and it will redirect to your localhost.

There are lots of good examples on Google.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the site from another computer, you can use the IP address of the server. The bash command to do this is `ifconfig` or `ip addr`

If your local address is, for example, `192.168.0.3`, then you can access the site via `192.168.0.3/workspace/sample`.